# Batch File inside Batch file - Call function not exceuting

Tags: batch-file, call

The code of my batch file looks like as below :

```
xcopy D:\FastTools\FTOutput\common\Displays D:\FastTools\TestTr 
PAUSE "Copy is over " 
call D:\FastTools\FTOutput\common\QLI\GP1039_command 
PAUSE "QLI is over "
```

Getting below messages:

```
C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop>CALL D:\FastTools\FTOutput\common\QLI\GP1039_command
'Version' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file. 

C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop>dssqld -r GP1039_object
CRL-E-ENOENT, no such file or directory DSSQ-E-QLD_FILOPN,
The input file could not be opened or read (file = 'GP1039_object.qli')
```

Note :Where GP1039_command is another batch file which calling others QLI files

Question: why i am getting messages as mentioned above.

Comment: you are getting those messages because those files (`GP1039_command` and `DSSQ-E-QLD_FILOPN`) are not there where you assume them to be.

Comment: @PA, GP1039_Command is fine but it appears to be running version, which is not.

Comment: I believe you really need to show us `D:\FastTools\FTOutput\common\QLI\GP1039_command.bat`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, the *first* one is probably caused by the fact that your `GP1039_Command` file tries to execute a `version` command. It's a little hard to see what the problem is without knowing the contents of that file.

One possibility is that it's supposed to be using `ver` which is the `cmd.exe` way of getting the version. Another is that there *is* a version executable but it's not installed or not on your path. Yet another is that `GP1039_Command` may not even *be* a valid `cmd` file.

The other error is even trickier, since it's an application one rather than a `cmd.exe` one. `ENOENT` is usually shorthand for "error: no entry" meaning something couldn't be found. In this case, it's the `GP1039_object.qli` file.

This may be because you're not in the directory you're expected to be in (unless the QLI file is actually *on* your desktop), although that's just a best guess, since I have no idea what QLI even is :-)

Still, even without knowing that, the points above should be helpful in determining the cause of your problem.

Comment: Another is that there is a version executable but it's not installed or not on your path. This was the case in my stated problem.